# Android Studio - optimize

Tags: java

I ask to you, How can I optimize this code because it is too much long:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5;

String matrix[][]={{a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1},
                   {a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2},
                   {a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3},
                   {a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g4},
                   {a5,b5,c5,d5,e5,f5,g5};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    a2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    a3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a3);
    a4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a4);
    a5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a5);
    b1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    c1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c1);
    c2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c2);
    c3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c3);
    c4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c4);
    c5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c5);
}
```

I can't find the solution, you can help me?

Comment: Use [for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/468/for-loops#t=201703181628251391868).

Comment: also you can use a list of imageviews

Comment: Can you do to me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following untested code utilizing the [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) method:

```
final int W = 7;
final int H = 5;
ImageView a[][] = new ImageView[W][H];
final String matrix[][]={{"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1"},
                         {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2"},
                         {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3"},
                         {"a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4"},
                         {"a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5", "g5"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(matrix[i][j], "id", getPackageName());
            a[i][j] = ((ImageView) findViewById(id));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Press Debug button instead of Run to localize the crash

Comment: I try debug,  it crash at the start at the declaration of  W

Comment: Copy the text here

Comment: final int W = 7;
    final int H = 5;
    ImageView a[][] = new ImageView[W][H];
    final String matrix[][] = {{"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1"},
            {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2"},
            {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3"},
            {"a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4"},
            {"a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5", "g5"}};

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(matrix[i][j], "id", getPackageName());
                a[i][j] = ((ImageView) findViewById(id));
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Have you an idea?

Comment: The crash text frim the debugger

Comment: I don't find the text, where is it?